# Changing the current cell selection to row select

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form in which we have a `DataGridView`. The property of that is cell select and I have a `ContextMenustrip` in which there is a menu named select all when select all is clicked it should change the property of `DataGridView` of the selected cell to the `FullRowSelect` and the selection should be on the same row which I have clicked. the problem is when i click on a cell the default property is cell select and when I click on select all of the `ContextMenustrip` the selected cell is not selected and I have to re-select that row I want that when the form opens and when i click on particular cell and when i click on select all of the `ContextMenustrip` is clicked then the same row should be selected on which I have clicked the cell previously this is my code.

```
private void selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to select the entire row when the "Select All" option of a context menu is clicked.  If that is correct, you might try:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Selected = true;
```

or

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    cell.OwningRow.Selected = true;
```

You will need to remove the following line first:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

The above line will put the DataGridView into full-row select mode, in which the SelectedCells property will not be used, and you will then see the following exception when you click the Select All option in your context menu.

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

The entire function should look like this:

```
private void selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        cell.OwningRow.Selected = true;
}
```

Note that the user will need to (left) click the cell whose row they want to select *before* right-clicking to bring up the context menu.  Otherwise, the selection will not change, and the previously-selected cell's row will be selected.

Comment: sir i dont know what you have given but when i click on select all menu strip then it errors with "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" i want that when the form opens then when i select the cell and right click on that and select the menystrip as select all then it will select the whole row of the cell which i have selected. now you got what i want?

Answer (score 1):

Take selected cells *before* you change selection mode and select those cell's rows *after* selection mode is changed:

```
var selectedCells = dataGridView1.SelectedCells;            
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in selectedCells)            
    dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Why you have to do that? Because `DataGridView` control clears selection when it's selection mode changes. See remarks on [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) property at msnd:

> Changing the value of the SelectionMode property clears the current selection.

Comment: sir in your case when i click the other cells the property is set to row select... how can i change the property to cell select means. when i start a form and when i click then the default property is cell select and then if i click select all the the selected cell will be set to full row select property and if i change the selection to another cell then it should be cell select. can it be done sir?

Comment: @shariq_khan sure it can be done - change SelectMode when selecting new cell

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void employeesDataGridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTestInfo;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            hitTestInfo = employeesDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader || hitTestInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                if (hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex != -1)
                    employeesDataGridView.CurrentCell = employeesDataGridView[hitTestInfo.ColumnIndex, hitTestInfo.RowIndex];
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(employeesDataGridView, employeesDataGridView.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position));
            }
        }       
    }

    private void selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employeesDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        var current = employeesDataGridView.CurrentCell;
        if (current == null) return;
        if (current.ColumnIndex == -1)
            return;
        if (current.RowIndex == -1)
            return;
        employeesDataGridView[current.ColumnIndex, current.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        employeesDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    }
```